# Android KeyCode of Underscore

Tags: android, keyevent, keycode

I'm implementing a custom keyboard for Android from an xml but I can't find the KeyCode for the underscore.
I tried to print the keycode overriding onKeyDown but does not seem to work.
Where can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

It is just decimal 95, or hex 5F.

Comment: Already tried, I put the row
   <Key android:codes="95" android:keyLabel="_" />
but does not work

Answer (score 0):

My solution:
Its the same as "minus" key's: "KEYCODE_MINUS Constant Value: 69 (0x00000045)"

Details:
keycodes are used in KeyEvents. When you create a KeyEvent, you must pass keycode **and metastate** as parameters to the keyevent's constructor.

With "metastate" you can specify that Shift is pressed (and many more).
Dispatching this keyevent to the activity the activity itself will do the trick, your view will display the underscore.

**Code:**

```
dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(0,0,KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MINUS,0,KeyEvent.META_SHIFT_ON))
```